# Select query using *

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am building a form which needs to extract values from the table 'tblContacts' shown in the two queries i built below.  I don't understand why when building my control text boxes on my form, why the first query works fine, but the second query does not allow me to extract specific values from the contacts table.  For example, using the second query, I was not able to get the correct value in the field tblContacts.Level.  However, when i built the specified query (the second example) all works fine. My first instinct tells me that there is something in the properties on the form which I need to change, but until now, I am having no luck.

Example 1 (which does not work)

```
sql_get = " SELECT * FROM [tblContacts] INNER JOIN [tblteams] ON [tblcontacts].[Team] = [tblteams].[ID]  WHERE [tblTeams].[team]= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "'"
Me.frmstaticdatadepartments08.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Example 2 (works fine)

```
sql_get = "SELECT tblContacts.CompleteName, tblContacts.CurrentPosition, tblContacts.Level, tblContacts.ContractType, tblContacts.JobTitle, tblContacts.ID, tblContacts.Foto FROM tblContacts INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblContacts.Team = tblTeams.ID WHERE [tblTeams].[team]= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "'"
Me.frmstaticdatadepartments08.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Comment: We're missing details. What other code is there to handle the result from the query? The SQL statement itself seems fine. Also, is there an error you're getting? Does the debugger tell you anything?

Comment: It might be a problem with the duplicate column names for each table. For example if you have column id in tblContacts and also id in tblteams, selecting all * will generate results with duplicate column id for each table

Comment: then maybe (it's stupid) but you can try :`SELECT tblContacts.*`

Comment: There was a prior error message regarding duplicate column names. I think Avi is on to something.

Comment: Bravo Scraaappy!  I posted the solution using your suggestion.

Comment: @ Scraaappy, not sure how to give you credit for the solution.

Comment: one vote as useful is ok, thanks !;)

Comment: Since you asked, one way to give scraaappy credit for the solution is to delete your answer.  Then he can post it himself and you can vote for it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @ Scraaappy, if you copy and paste my answer I will delete mine and accept yours (or feel free to post it in your own words).

Comment: @ Scraaappy & company, i am about to post a similar question with the same query but after adding another table, i am having issues. Your attention would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solve the problem :
    `sql_get = "SELECT tblContacts.*, tblContacts.CurrentPosition, tblContacts.Level, tblContacts.ContractType, tblContacts.JobTitle, tblContacts.ID, tblContacts.Foto FROM tblContacts INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblContacts.Team = tblTeams.ID WHERE [tblTeams].[team]= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "'"`
PS : thnks for your courtesy guys :)